# how to write multiple ifs in html

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I have to show the notification if there is some result.
Like, if there is a new message, I need to show message. I have three scenarios.
I am using

```
    <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${formObj.msgNo != 0}">
```

It is working fine, but the problem is if one condition is met, others are skipped because it is if else block.
I want to have rather multiple ifs. Again I can use multiple

```
<c:choose>
```

but the main problem with that is I need to show on the page "There is no new notification" if none of the 3 conditions are met. Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: there's also `<c:otherwise>`. It's just a matter figuring out how to nest and group the tags. Warning: it's easy to write unmaintainable code this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have multiple

```
<c:if>
```

and for the case of no notification, you can have something like

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${formObj.msgCount == 0}">
     "Here comes your no notification message"
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
     Multiple <c:if></c:if> conditions
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

It should handle your use case.